# Can I mandate that a function in a base class is always run from a derived class' __init__?

Tags: python

I have an abstract base class `BudgetCategories` and a class, `BudgetCategoriesFromFile`, derived from it:

```py
from abc import ABCMeta
import csv

class BudgetCategories(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._budget_categories: list[str] = []

    def _check_budget_categories_are_unique(self) -> None:
        lower_case_budget_categories = [bc.lower() for bc in self._budget_categories]
        if len(lower_case_budget_categories) != len(set(lower_case_budget_categories)):
            duplicates = set(
                [
                    bc
                    for bc in lower_case_budget_categories
                    if lower_case_budget_categories.count(bc) > 1
                ]
            )
            raise ValueError(
                f"Budget categories must be unique. Duplicates: {duplicates}"
            )

    @property
    def budget_categories(self) -> list[str]:
        return self._budget_categories

class BudgetCategoriesFromFile(BudgetCategories):
    def __init__(self, path_to_budget_categories_csv_file: str) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        with open(path_to_budget_categories_csv_file, "r") as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                self._budget_categories.append(row[0])
        self._check_budget_categories_are_unique()
```

I want to mandate that `_check_budget_categories_are_unique()` is always called from any class derived from `BudgetCategories`. Is there a way to accomplish this?

I could call `_check_budget_categories_are_unique()` from the `budget_categories` property getter but that is too late, I want to call it during object creation.

Any critique of this code structure is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a metaclass:

```py
import abc
import functools

class Wrapper(abc.ABCMeta):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, namespace):
        # Run the `ABCMeta` initialization
        super().__init__(name, bases, namespace)
        
        # Override the declared `__init__` method to call
        # `self._check_budget_categories_are_unique()`
        # automatically at the end of its execution
        init_method = cls.__init__
        @functools.wraps(init_method)
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            init_method(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self._check_budget_categories_are_unique()
        cls.__init__ = __init__
```

Usage:

```py
class BudgetCategories(metaclass=Wrapper): ...

class BudgetCategoriesFromList(BudgetCategories):
    def __init__(self, categories: list) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        self._budget_categories.extend(categories)

        # No need to call `self._check_budget_categories_are_unique()` here

print(BudgetCategoriesFromList(['a', 'b'])) 
# ok
print(BudgetCategoriesFromList(['a', 'b', 'a'])) 
# ValueError: Budget categories must be unique. Duplicates: {'a'}
```

Comment: Would be a good idea to `@functools.wraps()` the new `__init__`.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can mandate it in a way that it can't be subverted.

If you want to make sure someone implementing a subclass doesn't accidentally forget to include that call, you could add a flag:

```
class BudgetCategories(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._budget_categories: list[str] = []
        self.__uniqueness_checked = False

    def _check_budget_categories_are_unique(self) -> None:
        # ... code ...
        self.__uniqueness_checked = True

    @property
    def budget_categories(self) -> list[str]:
        if not self.__uniqueness_checked:
            raise ValueError(f'{type(self)} did not call _check_budget_categories_are_unique during object creation')
        return self._budget_categories
```

That way, on access to `budget_categories`, you can check if the uniqueness check was actually called.

---

On the checking algorithm: it has an accidental quadratic runtime (due to calling `list.count` inside a list). If that could be a problem, I suggest using `collections.Counter`. Something like this:

```
from collections import Counter

...

    def _check_budget_categories_are_unique(self) -> None:
        lower_case_budget_categories = Counter(bc.lower() for bc in self._budget_categories)
        if any(count > 1 for count in lower_case_budget_categories.values()):
            # subtract 1 the count of every category
            lower_case_budget_categories.subtract(lower_case_budget_categories.keys())
            # converting to set only to keep output the same, there are no duplicates in the Counter keys
            # + is necessary, though. it removes all categories with 0 duplicates.
            duplicates = set(+lower_case_budget_categories)
            raise ValueError(
                f"Budget categories must be unique. Duplicates: {duplicates}"
            )
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a nice solution. I did (sort of) know about Counter() but you still showed me some useful tricks there

Comment: namely, a quick way of subtracting 1 from each count, and the + unary operator